# How to create embeded array list using pymongo and updat it (in python)?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, non-relational-database

How can I create as below showing mongodb  collocation using pymongo in mongodb python, and how insert new object only address array ?

```
  {
   _id: "joe",
   name: "Joe Bookreader",
   addresses: [
                {
                  street: "123 Fake Street",
                  city: "Faketon",
                  state: "MA",
                  zip: "12345"
                },
                {
                  street: "1 Some Other Street",
                  city: "Boston",
                  state: "MA",
                  zip: "12345"
                }
              ]
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use $push

if (_id_exists):

```
        newAdrz = {"$push": {"addresses": 
                            {
                                street: "1 Some Other Street", 
                                city: "Boston",
                                state: "MA", 
                                zip: "12345"
                            }}
                   }

        self.collection.update({_id: "joe"}, newAdrz)
```

else:

```
        root = {_id: "joe",name: "Joe Bookreader",
            addresses: [
            {
              street: "123 Fake Street",
              city: "Faketon",
              state: "MA",
              zip: "12345"
            }]
                }

          self.collection.insert(root)
```

This will update the addresses array if _id already exists in the mongodb